# Using autofocus and text_field form helpers in Rails

Tags: ruby, forms, html

How do I include the '`autofocus`' attribute on an `HTML5` form using the `text_field` form helper in `Rails`?

e.g. `<%= f.text_field :email %>`
Where does autofocus go?

Thanks

Answer (score 62):

`f.text_field :email, autofocus: true`

Comment: Ah, that works. Was looking it to generate 
<input id="user_email" name="user[email]" type="text" autofocus>
But autofocus="true" works too.

Thanks

Comment: For me, the autofocus="true" doesn't work and the autofocus=>"true" just works when displaying the page with Chrome and Arora (not with IE and Firefox)...

Comment: Note that the answer is `:autofocus=>true` and not `:autofocus=>"true"`. This works correctly without the quotation marks and generates the HTML: `autofocus="autofocus"`.

Answer (score 11):

This will work:

```
text_field_tag :reseller, '', autofocus: true
```

Note the empty `value` argument.

Answer (score 8):

`<%= f.text_field :email, nil, :autofocus => true %>`
will work.

similarly, if you want to use other HTML5 attributes and CSS classes, you can write :

`<%= f.text_field :email, nil, :autofocus => true, :placeholder => "Your email Here", :class => "active", :style => "color: #333;" %>`